# Twitter REST API consistency with ID placement

Tags: api, twitter

Can someone explain to me in, in REST terms, Twitter's design decision with the parameter placement in these two calls? It seems that the :id placement is inconsistent and arbitrary (although clearly this was deliberate).

```
GET statuses/:id/retweeted_by
Show user objects of up to 100 members who retweeted the status.

GET statuses/retweets/:id
Returns up to 100 of the first retweets of a given tweet.
```

There are other similar examples throughout their API (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api), so I'm definitely missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up checking with a friend at Twitter, who says:

> "I just talked with the guy who originally wrote those two API
>   endpoints, and he doesn't remember why. To answer your question,
>   though, there probably isn't a good RESTful reason for that design."

Answer (score 0):

*Just making guesses here*

Someone at Twitter once pointed out that the Twitter API runs on several servlets. I can only assume that this was related - it's easier to map `/retweets/*` than to map every single combination.

**Update**: I think that the history of the API itself can also be relevant. Twitter's API hasn't really changed much over the past years, and if it did change then it would be because new features would be added. An endpoint like `GET statuses/show/:id` is *old*, while `GET statuses/retweets/:id` is newer. If Twitter at some point decided to change naming conventions, they couldn't just rename the old ones, since it would break applications.

Another theory of mine is that `GET statuses/retweets/:id` actually doesn't refer to the Tweet `:id` itself, but is about the tweets that were based on it. `GET statuses/:id/retweeted_by` is directly related to the tweet itself, by returning users and not other statuses.

I too am often puzzled by the naming consistency. I'm sure they have their reasons though.

Comment: Because the different apis are implemented in different servlets, consistency suffers?  Left hand not talking to right hand?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, fair point, that doesn't sound very likely. I've updated my post with some other theories :-)